# Tensorflow: No shape function registered for standard op: ExtractGlimpse. Where do I add my code for the shape function?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to build a tensorflow graph using `tf.image.extract_glimpse`.

Unfortunately I think there is a bug in the API itself. I am receiving the error `No shape function registered for standard op: ExtractGlimpse`

There is actually the following code in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/attentions_ops.py` :

```
@ops.RegisterShape("ExtractGlimpse")
def _ExtractGlimpseShape(op):
  """Shape function for ExtractGlimpse op."""
  input_shape = op.inputs[0].get_shape().with_rank(4)
  unused_size_shape = op.inputs[1].get_shape().merge_with(
      tensor_shape.vector(2))
  offsets_shape = op.inputs[2].get_shape().merge_with(
      input_shape[:1].concatenate([2]))
  offsets_shape = offsets_shape
  size_value = tensor_util.ConstantValue(op.inputs[1])
  if size_value is not None:
    height = size_value[0]
    width = size_value[1]
  else:
    height = None
    width = None
  return [tensor_shape.TensorShape(
      [input_shape[0], height, width, input_shape[3]])]
```

For some reason this function isn't being used properly, however it's not entirely clear from the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html#implement-a-shape-function-in-python) where exactly this function is called.

In which python file is this function supposed to be called, and how does the call need to be used?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a bug in TensorFlow: the shape function is defined in the correct place, but the code in `attention_ops.py` is never executed, so the shape function is never registered.

I will fix it upstream, but in the meantime you can fix it by adding the following line to your program:

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import attention_ops
```

Comment: Cheers, importing the file has sorted it for the time being